# "enables no policy" vs. "does not enable any policy"

Tags: grammaticality

I recently asked for a change to some project's documentation, to change this sentence:

> By default, Pyramid enables no authorization policy.

It felt awkward, and it caused me to pause while reading, so I changed it to:

> Pyramid does not enable any authorization policy by default.

Are both forms correct?

Comment: What about: `No authorization policy is enabled by default`

Answer (score 1):

Both are equally legit:

> There is no such thing as a free lunch.

vs (the more stuffy)

> There is not such a thing as a free lunch.

Jane Eyre - Chapter 14

> You ought to have replied no such thing.

Jane Eyre - Chapter 34

> There are no such things as marble kisses or ice kisses, ..

One of the statements of the hippocratic oath translated in English:

> I will prescribe regimens for the good of my patients according to my ability and my judgment and never do harm to anyone.

An equally legit translation:

> I will ... and do NO harm to anyone.

It depends on whether the documentation policies of your software product would enforce formal and more stuffy language patterns or would encourage more colloquial expressions.

> I don't do no harm to nobody.